# Bucle JQUERY para aplicar estilo a un elemento que cumpla una condición en dos tablas diferentes

Tags: jquery

Os cuento:

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    var testimonialElements = $(".GRID");
    for(var i=0; i<testimonialElements.length; i++){
     $('th:visible:eq(0)').css("border-radius","6px 0 0 6px");
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es aplicar ese estilo CSS **al primer elemento th visible de cada una de las dos tablas** que tengo. En cambio, tan **solo me lo aplica al primer elemento th visible de la primera tabla**.

Tengo chequeado que testimonialElements.length vale 2, eso es correcto. ¿De qué forma debería ser la instrucción de dentro del for para que me lo aplique al primer TH visible de cada una de las dos tablas de la clase GRID?

Un saludo y gracias

**EDITO: Código HTML de las tablas**

```html
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">57</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">58</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">57</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">58</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: pódrias incluir tu codigo de las tablas...como estan formadas..!!

Comment: ese `eq(0)` es equivalente a decir "la primera ocurrencia" o "la ocurrencia con índice 0" simplemente saca esa parte del selector y déjalo así `'th:visible'`

Comment: Claro. aquí van. Lo del eq 0 si lo quito acaba por aplicar el estilo a todos los th y no es lo que quiero, solo debería afectar al primer th no oculto de cada una de las tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso específico podes usar un `.each()` para las tablas de clase `.GRID` y dentro de la iteración buscar con `find()` los `th:visible` y aplicar el css sólo al primero con `.first()`.

```
$('.GRID').each(
  function() {
    $(this).find('th:visible').first().css({
      borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
    });
  }
);
```

```js
$('.mTabla').each(
  function() {
    $(this).find('th:visible').first().css({
      background: "yellow",
      borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf2" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Para casos mas generales del tipo "aplicar CSS al primer elemento de tipo+clase X en varios grupos" donde "primer" es relativo al grupo (y no siempre es el `:first-child` o `:first-of-type`), hay varias opciones, aquí hay 3, la tercera es la mas compacta (busca, filtra, aplica css).

**Opción 1**

Modificar todos los `th:visible` y "desmodificar" todos los `th` que no son el primer `th:visible` (todo `th` que sea hermano y esté a continuación de un `th:visible`)

```
$("th:visible").css({
  borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
});
$("th:visible~th").css({
  borderRadius: 0,
});
```

```js
$("th:visible").css({
  background: "yellow",
  borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
});
$("th:visible~th").css({
  background: "none",
  borderRadius: 0,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Opción 2**

Variación del caso específico. No muy eficiente pero permite no saber el parent a priori, para todos los `th:visible` buscar el elemento padre y por cada padre buscar el primer `th:visible`

```
$("th:visible").parent().each(function() {
  $(this).find("th:visible").first().css({
    borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
  })
});
```

```js
$("th:visible").parent().each(function() {
  $(this).find("th:visible").first().css({
    background: "yellow",
    borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Opción 3**

Variación de opción 1 usando el filtro `.not()` de jQuery, encuentra todos los `th:visible` e ignora aquellos `th` hermanos que estén precedidos por un `th:visible`

```
$("th:visible").not("th:visible~th").css({
  borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
});
```

```js
$("th:visible").not("th:visible~th").css({
  background: "yellow",
  borderRadius: "6px 0 0 6px",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">57</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td style="display: none;">58</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Notas**

Opción 1 y opción 3 basados en la respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1423096 de [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)